# How to add a custom link in YouTube description?

Tags: html, youtube

Just as here:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CUxH_rWSI1k

I know that "http://..." link becomes clickable but in the example above it is totally different. And... awesome.

UPD. This IS NOT a question about how to make a link to specific time of YouTube video.

Comment: [SOLVED] just insert time in format `m:ss` and the rest will be done automatically.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this has absolutely nothing to do with programming

Answer (score 6):

It appears that if you just type the timecode you want, like 01:12 into the description field, it will make that a link to that time in the video.

Answer (score 4):

What you see there are shortened links, via https://goo.gl/

You can not link some text with an url in a video description in Youtube.

Answer (score 3):

The links in the youtube description you shared used the "shortened URL" service by google. To do this, go to "https://goo.gl" and put in the destination URL you want to shorten, them choose "Shorten URL". This will generate a shortened URL of the original link.

There are other services like that on the internet where you can also choose a customized or an alias shortened hyperlink, using your own text. A popular one is https://tinyurl.com/

Answer (score 2):

It is very simple. Just type the time point in this format
x:xx or xx:xx
It will become a hyper-link to a specific time point as you given. That's a great for long music albums to select each soundtrack included. Watch an example as follows;
Sinhala Songs MP3 List ► Play Jukebox 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=u0Ji7XDTo3Q